# How do I protect a shared google sheet with and still allow the script button to work?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-macros, google-apps-script-addon

I have a sheet that is shared with quite a few people.  They are supposed to fill in 5 cells, click the script button and it will insert the text below and sort it by date.

I created the script and assigned it to the button for this.

I need to protect the entire sheet except the 5 cells and the button.

When I add the protection nobody can click on the button.  Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can use Protected Ranges to protect the sheet from edit with the exception of pre-defined cells.*

#### Steps:

- Follow the menu item `Data > Protected sheets and ranges` from the Sheets User Interface.
- Click on the `+ Add a sheet or range` button in the newly-opened sidebar.
- Click the `Sheet` tab.
- Select which of the Sheets you wish to have protected.
- Mark the `Except certain cells` check-box with a click (✓) and select in A1 notation the 5 cells you wish for users to edit. For example `D1:D6`.
- Click `Ok`
- Click `Set permissions`
- Keep `Restrict who can edit this range` selected with `Only you` as the selection in the drop-down, and press `Done`.

This is enough - from here anyone you share the sheet with will have edit access to the specific five cells you specified in the exception rule. The button is also clickable as long as the user has authenticated the function to run as them.

#### References:

- [Docs Editors Help - Protect, hide, and edit sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656)